# VBEMenuButton Class

Tags: vba

The VBEMenuButton class simplifies creating menu items in the VBE Editor.  When Excel opens, the `Auto_Open()` routine in my Personal Macros book is triggered and my commands are added to the VBE Editor Menus.

The example code adds two menu items to the Menu toolbar Tools popup menu: "Backup ActiveWorkbook" and "Update ActiveWorkbook TableDefs".

[image: VBE Editor Tools Menu]

---

### VBEInit: Standard Module

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()
    Const MenuName As String = "Menu Bar"
    Const SubMenuName As String = "Tools"
    Static VBEButtons As Collection
    
    VBEMenuButton.DeleteAllVBEMenuButtons
    Set VBEButtons = New Collection
    VBEButtons.Add VBEMenuButton.Create(MenuName:=MenuName, SubMenuName:=SubMenuName, BeginGroup:=True, _
        Caption:="Backup ActiveWorkbook", wb:=ThisWorkbook, OnAction:="ActiveWorkbookBackUp")
    
    VBEButtons.Add VBEMenuButton.Create(MenuName, SubMenuName, False, "Update ActiveWorkbook TableDefs", ThisWorkbook, "UpdateActiveWorkbookTableDefs")
        
End Sub

Public Sub Auto_Close()
    VBEMenuButton.DeleteAllVBEMenuButtons
End Sub
```

### VBEMenuButton: Class

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "VBEMenuButton"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private Const TagName = "My VBEMenuButton"

Public Button As CommandBarControl
Public WithEvents EventHandler As VBIDE.CommandBarEvents
Attribute EventHandler.VB_VarHelpID = -1

Public Property Get Create(MenuName As String, SubMenuName As String, BeginGroup As Boolean, Caption As String, wb As Workbook, OnAction As String) As VBEMenuButton
    With New VBEMenuButton
                     
        Set .Button = Application.VBE.CommandBars(MenuName).Controls(SubMenuName).Controls.Add
        With .Button
            .Caption = Caption
            .BeginGroup = BeginGroup
            .OnAction = "'" & wb.Name & "'!" & OnAction
            .Tag = TagName
        End With
        Set .EventHandler = Application.VBE.Events.CommandBarEvents(.Button)
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As VBEMenuButton
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Private Sub EventHandler_Click(ByVal CommandBarControl As Object, Handled As Boolean, CancelDefault As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Run CommandBarControl.OnAction
    Handled = True
    CancelDefault = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub DeleteAllVBEMenuButtons()
    Dim Ctrl As Office.CommandBarControl
    Set Ctrl = Application.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:=TagName)
    Do Until Ctrl Is Nothing
        Ctrl.Delete
        Set Ctrl = Application.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:=TagName)
    Loop
End Sub
```

My code was based off of Pearson Software Consulting: [Creating Menu Items In The VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbemenus.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Public Sub Auto_Close()
>     VBEMenuButton.DeleteAllVBEMenuButtons
> End Sub
> ```

This is a bit weird IMO; why should a button have the power to delete other buttons? It basically invalidates other instances of the button class without them knowing. What would happen if I try to access `VBEButtons(1).Button` after the control it refers to has been deleted? You protect yourself from this scenario with `Static`:

> ```
> Public Sub Auto_Open()
>     Static VBEButtons As Collection
>     
>     VBEMenuButton.DeleteAllVBEMenuButtons
>     Set VBEButtons = New Collection
>     VBEButtons.Add VBEMenuButton.Create(...
> ```

... basically scoping the `VBEMenuButton` to a single procedure to prevent unexpected usage. However this scoping is only *a convention* for consumers of your class. Conventions are not enforced - and what if you refactor that `VBEMenuButtons` collection into module scope (perhaps there is some cleanup to do of other resources that necessitates access to the button objects), then any code could access it when it is in an invalid orphaned state following a call to `DeleteAllVBEMenuButtons`.

Long story short, a  method of *a member of a collection* should not be able to modify the state of the entire collection (as you have currently). That should be done by a function taking the collection as a parameter, or in OOP, a custom collection class which can clean up after itself - perhaps in the Terminate event - and which contains a set of Buttons to handle the click events.*

`DeleteAllVBEMenuButtons` would then become a normal member function of a `VBEMenuButtonCollection` class which loops through the internal collection of button event handlers, deleting the corresponding control (and removing the need for a tag I guess)

---

*Speaking of handling events, [apparently you should use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41066408/6609896) the `Click` event of the `CommandBarButton` class *not* the `CommandBarEvents` class because:

> [...] Office 2010 64-bit doesn't support CommandBarEvents (it crashes if
> used).

---

#### Parameters

> ```
> Public Property Get Create(MenuName As String, SubMenuName As String, BeginGroup As Boolean, Caption As String, wb As Workbook, OnAction As String)
>
> Private Sub EventHandler_Click(ByVal CommandBarControl As Object, Handled As Boolean, CancelDefault As Boolean)
> ```

should probably become (more explicit):

```
Public Property Get Create(ByVal MenuName As String, SubMenuName As String, ByVal BeginGroup As Boolean, ByVal Caption As String, ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal OnAction As String)

Private Sub EventHandler_Click(ByVal CommandBarControl As Object, ByRef outHandled As Boolean, ByRef outCancelDefault As Boolean)
```

Comment: My initial reaction was to you answer was a bit defensive.  My thoughts being that I just wanted to make Pearson's code super easy to implement. Then I started to think about how expanding it to have other controls, menus and submenus would be nice.  Yep your right.  I need to separate some of the concerns.  Nice work, I usually wait 3 or 4 days before accepting review.  Thanks!