# Building VBA and VBE Menus

Tags: vba

This is a follow up to [VBEMenuButton Class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274192/vbemenubutton-class).

After much trial and error I abandoned the previous approach.  I decided that it would be better to create a class to instantiate the menus.  When the class is terminated the menus are deleted.  This only works when the class is properly terminated.  When the VBA Crashes the menus remain but the handlers are destroyed.

For this reason I created two factory methods (InitCommandBarControl and InitCommandBar).  These methods will return the existing control is it exists.  If the control doesn't exists a new control is added and returned.

Overall I'm pretty happy with how it turned out but I'm open to criticism.   After all I wouldn't have gotten this far if Greedo didn't politely point out how bad my last attempt at it was.

[image: Code Demo]

### AutoOpenHandler: Module

```
Attribute VB_Name = "AutoOpenHandler"
Option Explicit
Private MyPersonalMenus As PersonalMenus

Sub InitPersonalMenus()
    Set MyPersonalMenus = New PersonalMenus
End Sub

Sub DeletePersonalMenus()
    Rem If the MyPersonalMenus is nothing I relinked so the Menus can be cleaned up
    If MyPersonalMenus Is Nothing Then _
        Set MyPersonalMenus = New PersonalMenus
    Set MyPersonalMenus = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Auto_Open()
    InitPersonalMenus
End Sub
```

### CommandHandlerRelay: Class

The Create method of the CommandHandlerRelay class

- Returns a new instance of the class
- Set a Reference to the a Callback object
- Stores the Procedure Name of the Callback object
- Creates a listener for the CommandBarControl

When the listener is triggered an Array containing the CommandHandlerRelay and CommandBarControl are passed to the Callback object's Procedure.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1 
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CommandHandlerRelay"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Option Explicit
Rem Original Code From Pearson Software Consulting
Rem Creating Menu Items In The VBA Editor: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbemenus.aspx

Public CallBackObject As Object
Public ProcName As String
Public Data As Variant

Public WithEvents EvtHandler As VBIDE.CommandBarEvents
Attribute EvtHandler.VB_VarHelpID = -1

Public Property Get Create(Ctrl As CommandBarControl, pCallBackObject As Object, pProcName As String) As CommandHandlerRelay
    With New CommandHandlerRelay
        Set .EvtHandler = Application.VBE.Events.CommandBarEvents(Ctrl)
        Set .CallBackObject = pCallBackObject
        .ProcName = pProcName
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As CommandHandlerRelay
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Private Sub EvtHandler_Click(ByVal CommandBarControl As Object, _
    handled As Boolean, CancelDefault As Boolean)

    'On Error Resume Next
    CallByName CallBackObject, ProcName, VbMethod, Array(Self, CommandBarControl)
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Tell VBIDE that we've handled the event.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    handled = True
    CancelDefault = True
End Sub
```

### CommandBarFactory: Module

```
Attribute VB_Name = "CommandBarFactory"
Option Explicit

Public Function InitCommandBarControl(Controls As CommandBarControls, ControlType As MsoControlType, TagId As String) As CommandBarControl
    Dim Ctrl As CommandBarControl
    Set Ctrl = Controls.Parent.FindControl(Tag:=TagId)
    If Ctrl Is Nothing Then
        Set Ctrl = Controls.Add(Type:=ControlType, Temporary:=True)
        Ctrl.Tag = TagId
    End If
    
    Set InitCommandBarControl = Ctrl
End Function

Public Function InitCommandBar(CBars As CommandBars, Ctrl As CommandBar, Name As String, Optional Position As Long, Optional MenuBar As String) As CommandBar
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ctrl = CBars(Name)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set Ctrl = CBars.Add(Name:=Name, Position:=Position, MenuBar:=MenuBar, Temporary:=True)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set InitCommandBar = Ctrl
End Function
```

### PersonalMenus: Class

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "PersonalMenus"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit
Private PersonalMenu As CommandBarPopup
Private ShowUserformsMenu As CommandBarPopup
Private WithEvents ShowUserformsListener As VBIDE.CommandBarEvents
Private ShowTablesMenu As CommandBarPopup
Private WithEvents ShowTablesListener As VBIDE.CommandBarEvents
Private WithEvents ClearImmediateWindowButton As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents ShowVBEditor As CommandBarButton

Option Explicit
Private PersonalMenu As CommandBarPopup
Private ShowUserformsMenu As CommandBarPopup
Private WithEvents ShowUserformsListener As VBIDE.CommandBarEvents
Private ShowTablesMenu As CommandBarPopup
Private WithEvents ShowTablesListener As VBIDE.CommandBarEvents
Private WithEvents ClearImmediateWindowButton As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents ShowVBEditor As CommandBarButton

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Rem Add "Personal" Menu to VBE Menu Bar
    Set PersonalMenu = InitCommandBarControl(MenuBar.Controls, msoControlPopup, "PersonalMenu")
    PersonalMenu.Caption = "Personal"
    
    Rem Add "Show Userforms" Menu Personal Menu
    Set ShowUserformsMenu = InitCommandBarControl(PersonalMenu.Controls, msoControlPopup, "ShowUserformsMenu")
    ShowUserformsMenu.Caption = "Show Userforms"
    
    Rem Add "Show Userforms" Menu Listener
    Rem When Clicked the Menu Adds a Submenu for each Workbook that has a Userform
    Rem A Menu Button is added for each Userform
    Set ShowUserformsListener = Application.VBE.Events.CommandBarEvents(ShowUserformsMenu)
    
    Rem Add "Show Tables" Menu Personal Menu
    Set ShowTablesMenu = InitCommandBarControl(PersonalMenu.Controls, msoControlPopup, "ShowTablesMenu")
    
    Rem Add "Show Tables" Menu Listener
    Rem When Clicked the Menu Adds a Submenu for each Workbook that has a ListObject
    Rem A Menu Button is added for each ListObject
    ShowTablesMenu.Caption = "Show Tables"
    Set ShowTablesListener = Application.VBE.Events.CommandBarEvents(ShowTablesMenu)
    
    Rem Init the ClearImmediateWindowButton
    Rem There is no need use a VBIDE.CommandBarEvents listener
    Rem Use WithEvents for non-dynamic ControlButton and ControlComboBox controls
    Set ClearImmediateWindowButton = InitCommandBarControl(PersonalMenu.Controls, msoControlButton, "ClearImmediateWindowButton")
    ClearImmediateWindowButton.Caption = "Clear Immediate Window"
    
    Rem Add a ShowVBEditor button to the Cell's context menu
    Set ShowVBEditor = InitCommandBarControl(CellMenu.Controls, msoControlButton, "ShowVBEditor")
    ShowVBEditor.Caption = "Show VBEditor"
End Sub

Private Function MenuBar() As CommandBar
    Set MenuBar = Application.VBE.CommandBars("Menu Bar")
End Function

Private Function CellMenu() As CommandBar
    Set CellMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")
End Function

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Rem Find our CommandBarControls and delte them if they exists
    On Error Resume Next
    InitCommandBarControl(MenuBar.Controls, msoControlPopup, "PersonalMenu").Delete
    InitCommandBarControl(CellMenu.Controls, msoControlPopup, "ShowVBEditor").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub ClearImmediateWindowButton_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
    Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"
End Sub

Rem This button is added to the Cell context menu
Private Sub ShowVBEditor_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
    With Application.VBE.MainWindow
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = vbext_ws_Maximize
    End With
    Rem CancelDefault needs to be set to true to prevent the control's OnAction method event from triggering
    Rem I do this so that I do not need to create a methos in a standard maodule to handle the button clock
    CancelDefault = True
End Sub

Private Sub ShowUserformsListener_Click(ByVal CommandBarControl As Object, handled As Boolean, CancelDefault As Boolean)
    Rem Delete All Existing Menu Items
    While ShowUserformsMenu.Controls.Count > 0
        ShowUserformsMenu.Controls(1).Delete
    Wend
    
    Static Listerners As Collection
    Set Listerners = New Collection
    
    AddShowUserFormMenus Listerners
    handled = True
    CancelDefault = True
End Sub

Private Sub AddShowUserFormMenus(Listerners As Collection)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Component As VBComponent
    Dim Handler As CommandHandlerRelay
    Dim Button As CommandBarButton
    Dim Menu As CommandBarPopup
    
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Set Menu = Nothing
        For Each Component In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
            Rem Check if the VBComponent is an Userform
            If Component.Type = vbext_ct_MSForm Then
                Rem Create a Menu for the current workbook's Userforms Menu Items
                If Menu Is Nothing Then
                    Set Menu = InitCommandBarControl(ShowUserformsMenu.Controls, msoControlPopup, wb.Name)
                    Menu.Caption = wb.Name
                End If
                Rem Add a Menu Button with the Userform Name as the Caption
                Set Button = InitCommandBarControl(Menu.Controls, msoControlButton, wb.Name & ":" & Component.Name)
                Button.Caption = Component.Name
                
                Rem Create a CommandHandlerRelay to listen for the Userform's Menu Item click event
                Rem Assign an array of relavent data to the CommandHandlerRelay Data Field
                Set Handler = CommandHandlerRelay.Create(Button, Me, "ShowUserFormHandler")
                Handler.Data = Array(wb, Component)
                Listerners.Add Handler
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Rem Handles the USerform Menu Item click event
Rem CommandHandlerRelay passes is an array of data when this macro is called
Public Sub ShowUserFormHandler(Args() As Variant)
    Dim Handler As CommandHandlerRelay
    Dim Ctrl As CommandBarControl
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Set Handler = Args(0)
    Set Ctrl = Args(1)
    Data = Handler.Data
    
    Dim Component As VBComponent
    Set Component = Data(1)
    
    With Component.DesignerWindow
        .Visible = True
        .SetFocus
        SendKeys "{F5}"
    End With
    
End Sub

Private Sub ShowTablesListener_Click(ByVal CommandBarControl As Object, handled As Boolean, CancelDefault As Boolean)
    Rem Delete All Existing Menu Items
    While ShowTablesMenu.Controls.Count > 0
        ShowTablesMenu.Controls(1).Delete
    Wend
    
    Static Listerners As Collection
    Set Listerners = New Collection
    
    AddShowTablesMenus Listerners
    handled = True
    CancelDefault = True
End Sub

Private Sub AddShowTablesMenus(Listerners As Collection)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Handler As CommandHandlerRelay
    Dim Button As CommandBarButton
    Dim Menu As CommandBarPopup
    Dim ListObject As ListObject
    
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Set Menu = Nothing
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            For Each ListObject In ws.ListObjects
                Rem Create a Menu for the current ListObject Menu Items
                If Menu Is Nothing Then
                    Set Menu = InitCommandBarControl(ShowTablesMenu.Controls, msoControlPopup, wb.Name)
                    Menu.Caption = wb.Name
                End If
                Rem Add a Menu Button with the ListObject Name as the Caption
                Set Button = InitCommandBarControl(Menu.Controls, msoControlButton, wb.Name & ":" & ListObject.Name)
                Button.Caption = ListObject.Name
                
                Rem Create a CommandHandlerRelay to listen for the Userform's Menu Item click event
                Rem Assign an array of relavent data to the CommandHandlerRelay Data Field
                Set Handler = CommandHandlerRelay.Create(Button, Me, "ShowUserTablesHandler")
                Handler.Data = Array(wb, ws, ListObject)
                Listerners.Add Handler
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Rem Handles the ListObject Menu Item click event
Rem CommandHandlerRelay passes is an array of data when this macro is called
Public Sub ShowUserTablesHandler(Args() As Variant)
    Dim Handler As CommandHandlerRelay
    Dim Ctrl As CommandBarControl
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Set Handler = Args(0)
    Set Ctrl = Args(1)
    Data = Handler.Data

    Dim ListObject As ListObject
    Set ListObject = Data(2)
    Application.Goto ListObject.HeaderRowRange, True
End Sub
```